# Selecting a pair of numbers with their maximized sum in a Numpy array structure (game theory)

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, game-theory

So I have the following code to compute and display the nash equilibrium probability distribution and utility of a determined game:

```
import numpy
import nash

game = [[[[0,3],[1,2]],[[2,3],[1,0]]],"ShSh","StagHunt"]


def NashStrategySelection(game):
    p1 = game[0][0]  
    p2 = game[0][1]   
    game = nash.Game(p1,p2)
    print (game)
    eqs = game.support_enumeration()
    eql = list(eqs)
    for item in eql:
        print ("Nash distribution", item)
    for s1,s2 in eql:
        row_utility = numpy.dot(numpy.dot(s1,p1),s2)
        print ("Row's utility", row_utility)
        col_utility = numpy.dot(numpy.dot(s1,p2),s2)
        print ("Col's utility", col_utility)
```

The result in this case is:

```
NashStrategySelection(game)
Bi matrix game with payoff matrices:

Row player:
[[0 3]
 [1 2]]

Column player:
[[2 3]
 [1 0]]
Nash distribution (array([ 1.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  1.]))
Nash distribution (array([ 0.,  1.]), array([ 1.,  0.]))
Nash distribution (array([ 0.5,  0.5]), array([ 0.5,  0.5]))
Row's utility 3.0
Col's utility 3.0
Row's utility 1.0
Col's utility 1.0
Row's utility 1.5
Col's utility 1.5
```

Being each pair of utilities the result of one of the possible equilibria (nash distribution).

The `Nash` package generates the game matrix and computes the Nash equilibrium (probability distribution)

I believe the `numpy.dot` references the index of the nash array with the game array. EDIT: It returns the product of the matrixes, not the index!

This case (stag hunt) is a classic case of multiple equilibria. What I need is to select and return one pair of strategies in this numpy array where the sum of utilities is maximized (in this case, Row=3 and Col=3). But they need to belong to the same pair to keep the nash properties (there are cases where the max for each player belong to different selections).

Anyone has an idea on how to do that?

Thank you in advance.